# Aws cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

[image: geeting error on 4th line of cloud formation template, can youbhelpme frds]

I have checked, but it's showing error on 4th line pls help me frds

Comment: VS Code marks the error at the beginning of the section that contains the error. Somewhere inside your Metadata you are missing a comma. I'd recommend re-creating it one part at a time which will show you where the error is occurring.
Also, please don't post screenshots of your code. They are very difficult to read.

Comment: Please paste the code into your question as TEXT, rather than using an image.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma in the line before "Metadata". If you have an error mark in a particular line, you usually need to check your inputs above. More about the basic structure of CloudFromation may be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).